# Array to String conversion error in Symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have a form from which i am fetching the data as array in controller from `$request->get()`  method and want to submit that data to database..

This is the array i am getting when i print the post variable:

```
Array
(

[country] => Array
    (
        [0] => 24
        [1] => 4
    )

[state] => Array
    (
        [0] => Cuando Cubango
        [1] => Badakhshan
    )

[activity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 5
    )

[activity_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

)
```

I want them to insert in database in this format:

```
country state            activity
24      Cuando Cubango   3  
24      Cuando Cubango   5
4       Badakhshan       3
```

What i have tried so far is this:

```
$active = $request->get('activity');
if (!empty($active)) {
    foreach ($active as $activity) {
        $states = $request->get('state');
        $c = $request->get('country');
        $Bidactivity = $active;
        foreach ($states as $state) {
            foreach ($Bidactivity as $orgact) {
                $activity_to_db = new Activity();
                $activity_to_db->setActivityid($active);
                $activity_to_db->setState($states);
                $activity_to_db->setBidOrganiser($organiserDetails);
                $activity_to_db->setCountry($c);
                $em->persist($activity_to_db);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting the array to string conversion error. Please guide.

Comment: your `setCountry` takes array as a parameter ? if not then you are passing country array `$c` to a function which needs a single value not array thats why you are getting this error its a guess because you have not posted definition of `Activity`

Comment: you mean i should setCountry and State outside the loop?

Comment: have you tried to put the $states and $c outside your loop?

Comment: yes  i just tried the error is still the same..

Comment: @Geetika read my comment again if a function needs single value then pass single value your post data contains array for each parameter you need to loop through each parameters data

Comment: include your entity metadata please.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because you pass an array to every field of your activity:

```
  $activity_to_db->setActivityid($active); /* is this [activity] => Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)*/
  $activity_to_db->setState($states); /* is this [state] => Array
(
    [0] => Cuando Cubango
    [1] => Badakhshan
)*/
  $activity_to_db->setBidOrganiser($organiserDetails); // doesn't occure, so whats that
  $activity_to_db->setCountry($c); /* is this [country] => Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 4
)*/
```

So anywhere there is the error.

Loop between the array with the highest number of elements as `$active = $request->get('activity');` 
Try the smt like

```
$states = $request->get('state');
 $c = $request->get('country');
 if (!empty($active)) {
      foreach ($c as $index=> $country) {
        foreach ($states as $state) {
           foreach ($active as $activity) {
            $activity_to_db = new Activity();
            $activity_to_db->setActivityid($activity);
            $activity_to_db->setState($state);
            $activity_to_db->setCountry($country);
            $em->persist($activity_to_db);
          }
        }
      }
 }
 $em->flush();
```

Comment: This only is inserting state and country in db not the activities....also the first country and state only not all selected ones

Comment: ok edited the code for you. Hope I got it right. Basically it saving for each country every state with every activity